# track product name multiple products

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I've very limited Javascript skills, and I am trying to put together a script that goes beyond my skills.

I am using Google Tag Manager in order to setup a script that captures the product name of a product that a user adds to his/her shopping cart.

So the thought is that when a user clicks an "add to cart" button, I also capture the name of the product that the user adds and store it in a variable. My problem is that I've no idea on how to do this when there are multiple products on the same page.

What would the script look like in order to capture the name of the product that is being added to the cart?

Page example can be found here:   [cxshop.azurewebsites.net](http://cxshop.azurewebsites.net)

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far as I have no clue where to start (VERY limited Javascript skills :). The add to cart button is being track by using GTM "Click - all elements" trigger, and then "some clicks" and "Click classes" "contains" "add to cart". So what I need in addition is a way to append/add the name of the product (product title) that is attached/related to that product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all you need to crate variable, which will find your product name**

1) Go to Variables -> User-Defined Variables -> New

2) Type -> Custom JavaScript

3) Name: Product Name

4) Code:

```
function(){    
    var element = {{Click Element}};
    return $.trim($('h2.product-title, h1[itemprop="name"]',element.closest('div[data-productid]')).text());
}
```

**Create trigger**

1) Go to Triggers -> New

Name: Add to cart trigger

Type: Click - All elements

`Click Element` - `matches CSS selector` - `.product-box-add-to-cart-button, .add-to-wishlist-button`

**Create tag**

1) Go to Tags -> News

Name: Add to cart tag

Type: Universal Analytics

Track type: Event

*Fill data, what you want to send into GA. For example:*

Category: Add to cart

Action: Click

Label: {{Product Name}}

Set trigger: "Add to cart trigger"

Comment: Thanks Victor, that was exactly what I was looking. Worked perfectly!